# Google doesn't like my WAMP server. Anyone have any ideas?

Tags: php, curl, http-post, google-api

Alright I'm at the end of the rope here. I've tried just about everything to try to get this working. I've done Google OAUTH API calls before on web hosts and everything works great, but when I use the same scripts on my WAMP server, google does not reply to my cURL posts. I've tested cURL post by posting to my own server as well as to this server someone set up:

http://www.newburghschools.org/testfolder/dump.php

And it works just fine. Here's the script I'm using after I get the user to allow my application:

```
<?

//This script handles the response from google. If the user as authed the app, it will continue the process by formulating another URL request to Google to get the users information. If there was an error, it will simply redirect to index.

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../src/php/google/initialize.php");

if (!isset($_GET['error'])) {
    //No error found, formulate next HTTP post request to get our auth token

    //Set URL and get our data encoded for POST

    $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

    $fields = array(
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'client_id' => $google['clientID'],
        'client_secret' => $google['clientSecret'],
        'redirect_uri' => "http://www.dealertec.com/scripts/php/google/reg_response.php",
        'grant_type' => "authorization_code"
    );

    //$data = http_build_query($fields);
    $data = "code=".$fields['code'].'&client_id='.$fields['client_id'].'&client_secret='.$fields['client_secret'].'&redirect_uri='.$fields['redirect_uri'].'&grant_type='.$fields['grant_type'];
    echo $data."<br> /";

    //Begin cURL function

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);

    //Decode the JSON and use it to make a request for user information
    print_r($response);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    /*if (!isset($response['error'])) {
        //No error in response, procede with final step of acquiring users information

        $apiURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=".$response['access_token'];

        $apiCall = curl_init($apiURL);  

        curl_setopt($apiCall, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($apiCall, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

        $apiResponse = curl_exec($apiCall);
        $apiResponse = json_decode($apiResponse, true);

        var_dump($apiResponse);
    }else{
        echo $response['error'];    
    }*/

}else{
    header("LOCATION: http://www.dealertec.com/");  
}

?>
```

When I echo out what is supposed to be the google response, all I get is a singular "/". When I run this same exact script on my webhost, after changing back the DNS IP, it works fine. I'm thinking either Google doesn't like my WAMP server and won't even talk to it, or perhaps it's something with my cURL configuration. It's only a minor annoyance not being able to develop for Google API on my WAMP server, but if anyone has any ideas whatsoever, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I used to have a lot of trouble with cURL on windows - so I switched to linux and haven't had a problem since.

Comment: I'm technically not running cURL on windows but on a virtual LINUX machine through WAMP. cURL works but for some reason google doesn't want to talk to my WAMP server. It's very weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a `FALSE` coming back from `curl_exec()`, but this is how I fixed it:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

hope this helps!

Comment: OMG it worked! I suspected it had something to do with SSL. Mucho thanks!